# How to connect to Oracle DB from Node.js with `createPool()`

Tags: node.js, oracle, connection, node-oracledb

I tried to connect oracle database to my project. I used the createpool in order to call this function in the future for all the necessary requests from the database.  my config.js file:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb')
oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT

const init = async function (query) {
  try {
    await oracledb.createPool({
      user: 'almat',
      password: 'almat789456123',
      connectString: '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=xepdb1)))'
    })

    console.log('Connection pool started')

    await dostuff(query)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('init() error: ' + err.message)
  } finally {
    // await closePoolAndExit()
  }
}

async function dostuff (query) {
  let connection
  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection()
    const sql = query
    const binds = [1]
    const options = { outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT }
    const result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, options)
    console.log(result)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close()
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    }
  }
}

async function closePoolAndExit () {
  console.log('\nTerminating')
  try {
    await oracledb.getPool().close(10)
    console.log('Pool closed')
    process.exit(0)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

process
  .once('SIGTERM', closePoolAndExit)
  .once('SIGINT', closePoolAndExit)

module.exports.init = init
```

My app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const config = require('./utils/config');

const app = express();

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Server running at port 3000')
})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  return res.render('index')
})

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  return res.render('login')
})

app.get('/getCustomerName', function (req, res) {
  const query = 'SELECT firstname FROM customer WHERE :b = 1'
  const result = config.init(query)
  //console.log(typeof result)
  return res.send(result)
})

module.exports = app
```

When I request http://localhost:3000/getCustomerName it returns empty json file and terminal throws this error: NJS-047: poolAlias "default" not found in the connection pool cache

Answer (score 0):

The `createPool()` call should be run once during app initialization, eg around the time you call `express()`.  From the [`createPool()` doc](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#createpool):

> This method creates a pool of connections with the specified user name, password and connection string. A pool is typically created once during application initialization.

`init()` shouldn't call `doStuff()`.  Once the pool is created, then your web listener handlers can call `dostuff()`.

Look at the basic example [webapp.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/webapp.js).

Also see the Oracle Magazine series [Build REST APIs for Node.js](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/build-rest-apis-for-nodejs-part-1) which has source code [here](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/tree/master/javascript/rest-api).

Comment: I can't understand logic, in the examples, I see that the sql query is inside one asynchronous function, and after this function is called inside the init()

Comment: In webapp.js,  handleRequest is called by the http module for each web request.   Play with the example(s) a bit and run them through a debugger.